# Django when multiple models have one-to-one relationship with user

Tags: django, one-to-one

for example:

Teacher's models.py：

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacherName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
```

student's models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(models.Model):
    studentName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grade=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
```

When I got a teacher's entity I can get it's user info by teacher.user

But when I got a user's entity how can I tell weather this user belongs to a teacher or a student?

Comment: Could you expand on the scenario please? You got a User instance and you want to know if that user is a teacher or student? Why not get the teacher/student directly?

Comment: For example in some case I want to know the identity of the logined user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether or not a User has a student or teacher attribute:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(id=5)
>>> hasattr(u, 'teacher')
False
>>> hasattr(u, 'student')
True
```

However, it seems like you'd be better off creating a custom user model in this case.